# Using FMOD to return an mp3 file's title, artist etc?

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm trying to use old fmodex get the title, artist and maybe album name of audio files that are currently being played with FMOD. After some googling I found that I should be reading the file's "tags". Some boilerplate code was provided but I get the feeling it was old since it doesn't quite work as expected.
My code for returning a song title as adapted from the boilerplate is as follows:

```
string FmodPlayer::getSongTitle()
{
    FMOD_TAG tag;
    char *title = NULL;
    audiostream->getTag("FILE", 0, &tag); //audiostream is whatever song is currently playing

    if (tag.type == FMOD_TAGTYPE_ID3V2)
    {
        audiostream->getTag("TIT2", 0, &tag);
        title = (char *)tag.data;
        //return ("ID3v2");
    }
    else
    {
        audiostream->getTag("TITLE", 0, &tag);
        title = (char *)tag.data;
        //return ("Wasn't an ID3v2");
    }
    string songName(title);
    return songName;
}
```

While this returns *something*, it isn't human readable and shows up as about 5 diamond-questionmarks or random chars. This is the same whether I return it as a string or a char array.
It should also be noted that I'm new to FMOD and therefore don't really know what I'm doing.

You'll notice I also included some commented out return statements to test whether the program saw the tag as an ID3v2 tag or not. It always showed that the mp3 file did not contain ID3v2 tags no matter how many mp3s I tried. I don't know what that means though, whether my MP3s are all the wrong kind or that the program is interpreting them wrong.

So, basically, what am I not seeing here? How do I get it to return a human readable song title? Once I have the song title down I am sure it'll be easy enough to do the same for artist, album etc.